# How do you show round brackets instead of square for bibliography links?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

The manual [here](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#user-biblio) shows links as square brackets, but I need round for Harvard citations. Is there a way to change this setting please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of [asiidoctor-bibtex](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-bibtex)? It is an extension to asciidoctor which supports different citation styles.